# Python GTK 3 - TreeView - Allow mouse selection on the row for copying contents

Tags: python, gtk, copy-paste, gtk3

I'm new on Python GTK and I was developing a simple TreeView that show several data:

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

# list of tuples for each variable, containing the environment variable name, its path, and the security category
variable_list = [
    ("$ENV1", "/usr/share/background/image.png", "Image"),
    ("$ENV2", "/home/user/script.py", "Program"),
    ("$ENV3", "/usr/share/icons/icon.png", "Image")
]


class TreeViewFilterWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="Environment Variable View")
        self.set_border_width(10)

        # Setting up the self.grid in which the elements are to be positioned
        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.grid.set_column_homogeneous(True)
        self.grid.set_row_homogeneous(True)
        self.add(self.grid)

        # Creating the ListStore model
        self.variable_liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, str, str)
        for variable_ref in variable_list:
            self.variable_liststore.append(list(variable_ref))
        self.current_filter_category = None

        # Creating the filter, feeding it with the liststore model
        self.category_filter = self.variable_liststore.filter_new()
        # setting the filter function, note that we're not using the
        self.category_filter.set_visible_func(self.category_filter_func)

        # creating the treeview, making it use the filter as a model, and adding the columns
        self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.category_filter)
        for i, column_title in enumerate(
            ["Variable", "Path", "Category"]
        ):
            renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
            column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, renderer, text=i)
            self.treeview.append_column(column)

        # creating buttons to filter by Category, and setting up their events
        self.buttons = list()
        for var_category in ["Image", "Program"]:
            button = Gtk.Button(label=var_category)
            self.buttons.append(button)
            button.connect("clicked", self.on_selection_button_clicked)

        # setting up the layout, putting the treeview in a scrollwindow, and the buttons in a row
        self.scrollable_treelist = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.scrollable_treelist.set_vexpand(True)
        self.grid.attach(self.scrollable_treelist, 0, 0, 5, 10)
        self.grid.attach_next_to(
            self.buttons[0], self.scrollable_treelist, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1, 1
        )
        for i, button in enumerate(self.buttons[1:]):
            self.grid.attach_next_to(
                button, self.buttons[i], Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1
            )
        self.scrollable_treelist.add(self.treeview)

        self.show_all()

    def category_filter_func(self, model, iter, data):
        """Tests if the Category in the row is the one in the filter"""
        if (
            self.current_filter_category is None
            or self.current_filter_category == "None"
        ):
            return True
        else:
            return model[iter][2] == self.current_filter_category

    def on_selection_button_clicked(self, widget):
        """Called on any of the button clicks"""
        # we set the current category filter to the button's label
        self.current_filter_category = widget.get_label()
        print("%s category selected!" % self.current_filter_category)
        # we update the filter, which updates in turn the view
        self.category_filter.refilter()


win = TreeViewFilterWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

When I run the script, the content of each row cannot be selected. Is there a way to select the content of these rows in order that I can right-click and copy the content?

In case I would like to highlight with the mouse cursor the text and then directly copy the highlighted content on the clipboard with a small message saying "The content has been copied", how could I reach these purposes?

Answer (score 0):

If selection was possible, this would have to be done by setting a property in [`Gtk.CellRendererText`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.CellRendererText), but I don't see a property that would make that possible, besides `editable`:

```
renderer.set_property("editable", True)
```

Making the cells editable would certainly allow users to copy from them, but this would suggest the contents could be changed. (If you don't connect to the `edited` signal, the text reverts after the input. This might feel very counterintuitive.)

If you the time, you could maybe write your own `CellRenderer` (I have no experience with this)

Another possibility would be to connect to the `button-released-event` of the `Gtk.TreeView` and copy the text to the clipboard if the user right-clicks.
Use [`Gtk.TreeView.get_path_at_pos`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeView.html#Gtk.TreeView.get_path_at_pos) to get the cell under the cursor.

```
def listclick(self, listview, event: Gdk.EventButton, *_unused) -> bool:
    """Handler for clicks on the list."""
    if (event.type == Gdk.EventType.BUTTON_RELEASE and event.button == 3):
        tup = listview.get_path_at_pos(event.x, event.y)
        if tup is not None:
            path, col, *unused = tup
            # Copy to Clipboard, depending on Path and Column
            # ...
            return True
    return False
```